# Is it the correct way to fetch multiple api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have to fetch two APIs, so I created two functions and call them simultaneously by calling those two methods in another one function as you can see in the code below. I'm not sure if this is the way to do it or should I put them both in `componentDidMount`?
Also how do I bind the word count of the textarea? I used `textlen` to count the words but I couldn't figure out how to use the `textlen` to show it in the paragraph element at the bottom

Below is the code, please guide me in the correct direction. I think I'm almost there but couldn't quite get the last piece of the puzzle:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default class MainText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      id: null,
      snippetDescription: "",
      scoredata: null,
      marksdata: null,
      textlen: 0,
    };
  }

  scoreanalysis = (snippetDescription, textlen) => {
    fetch("api/scores/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: "snippetDescription"
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        textdata => {
          this.setState({
            scoredata: textdata.scores,
            textlen: snippetDescription.split(" ").length
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };

  sportsanalysis = snippetDescription => {
    fetch("api/sports", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: "snippetDescription"
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        sportsdata => {
          this.setState({
            marksdata: sportsdata.data
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };

  analyse = (this.state) => {
    try {
      this.scoreanalysis(snippetDescription, textlen).bind(this);
      this.sportsanalysis(snippetDescription).bind(this);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error has occured while fetching data");
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
             <input
                type="text"
                id="titletext"
                onChange={title => this.setState({ title })}
              ></input>
            <textarea
              onChange={snippetDescription =>
                this.setState({ snippetDescription })
              }
            ></textarea>
         
            <Button onClick={() => this.analyse({ ...this.state })}> Analyse </Button>

            <p>{this.state.textlen} Words</p>
</>
)}
}
```

Comment: `this.scoreanalysis(snippetDescription, textlen)` will return `undefined` so `undefined.bind(this)` will **always** produce an error

Comment: how do I bind the functions then? can you also please shed some light on the word count. I don't know how to update the word count.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put your api's functions call into componentDidMount() because you execute them when you click the button

don't forget to put a return in your api's function call

```
  sportsanalysis = snippetDescription => {
    return fetch("api/sports", { // return HERE !!!!!!!!!!!
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: "snippetDescription"
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        sportsdata => {
          this.setState({
            marksdata: sportsdata.data
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
```

you may use await in your try catch like this.

```
analyse = async (this.state) => { // async here !!!
    try {
      await this.scoreanalysis(snippetDescription, textlen); // await here no need to bind
      await this.sportsanalysis(snippetDescription); // await here no need to bind
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error has occured while fetching data");
    }
}
```

Comment: why to use the return in the api call? also how do I update the textlen when the button is clicked that gives me the word count of the textarea

Comment: also I'm getting this error in the analyse function call " Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters"